# Travis CI fails with Child module ... does not exist

Tags: maven-3, travis-ci, maven-module

My git repository structure is as following:

```
-my-repo
  -.mvn
  -.travis.yml
  -my-parent-project
  -child-module
    -pom.xml
  -pom.xml
```

Where the parent pom includes

```
<modules>
    <module>child-module</module>
</modules>
```

And my `.travis.yml` looks like:

```
sudo: true
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk9
os: linux
before_install:
  - chmod +x ./my-project-parent/*
  - cd my-project-parent
install: true
script: ./mvnw clean install
cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.m2
```

When [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com/) build runs I'm getting:

```
[ERROR]   The project io.hvest:my-project-parent:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/travis/build/hVest/my-repo/my-project-parent/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Child module /home/travis/build/hVest/my-repo/my-project-parent/child-module of /home/travis/build/hVest/my-repo/my-project-parent/pom.xml does not exist
```

Locally maven runs smoothly, I don't understand why the build process running by [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com/) can't find the child-module, any ideas?